# raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate rails-dom-testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

First time I have installed ruby on rails. When I tried to run the server, following error occurred. I have searched a lot but could not find a solution. I have uninstalled `nokogiri 1.6.6` which was not working on Windows. After that I installed `1.8.+` version. Now I am facing this error.

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2112:in raise_if_conflicts: Unable to activate rails-dom-testing-2.0.1, because nokogiri-1.8.0-x86-mingw32 conflicts with nokogiri (~> 1.6.0) (Gem::ConflictError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1280:in activate
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1314:in block in activate_dependencies
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1300:in each
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1300:in activate_dependencies
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1282:in activate
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1314:in block in activate_dependencies
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1300:in each
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1300:in activate_dependencies
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1282:in activate
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:67:in block in gem
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:66:in synchronize
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:66:in gem
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/rails:22:in <main>
```